# Code can create the directory but throws the exception `UnauthorizedAccessException` while copying the file to a directory

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am getting `UnauthorizedAccessException` while copying the file to a directory, inside the `wwwroot`. However `Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolderPath);` creates the folder.

The code I am using to create the folder and copy the files is shown below.

```
public string UploadPdfFile(IFormFile file, string folderName)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // Define the file path
    string uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, @"uploads\books", $"{folderName}");


    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolderPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolderPath);


    // Save the file to the drive
    using (var stream = new FileStream(uploadFolderPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        file.CopyTo(stream);
    }

    return uploadFolderPath;
}
```

The error says:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Project\XX-Pedia\XX-Pedia\wwwroot\Uploads\Books\c1' is denied.

What is the solution for this?

I am running the visual studio in administrative mode.

This is strange because the code can create the folder but couldn't copy the files to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was missing the actual filename component...

```
string uploadFolderPath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, @"uploads\books", $"{folderName}");


if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolderPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolderPath);

//added this line
string filepath = Path.Combine(uploadFolderPath, file.FileName);

// Save the file to the drive
using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
{
    file.CopyTo(stream);
}
```